# Proving a certain path in an oriented graph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let **G** be an oriented graph with $2^k$ vertices and between every 2 vertices there is exactly 1 edge. I need to prove that, no matter the orientation of **G**'s edges, there is a path in **G** with **k + 1** different vertices.

Comment: An oriented graph with exactly one edge between each pair of vertices is called a *tournament*. A tournament with $n$ nodes contains a path with $n$ nodes, so there's a lot of slack in the statement you say you have to prove. Perhaps you misstated the question? Perhaps you want, not merely a path, but a ***transitive tournament*** on $k+1$ vertices?

Comment: A ***path*** is a set of distinct vertices $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_k$ with an edge from $a_i$ to $a_{i+1}$ for each $i.$ I suspect that you want something stronger, namely, an edge from $a_i$ to $a_j$ whenever $i\lt j.$ Did I guess right? You can prove that by induction on $k.$

Comment: **Hint.** Choose a vertex $v$ in your oriented complete graph $G$ with $2^k$ vertices. By the pigeonhole principle, either $v$ has (at least) $2^{k-1}$ incoming edges, or else it has (at least) $2^{k-1}$ outgoing edges. Now use the inductive hypothesis . . .

Comment: Eveything seems to be fine except the part with each vertex having either 2 to the power of k-1 outgoing or incoming edges

Comment: If $x$ is the number of outgoing edges and $y$ is the number of incoming edges, then $x+y=2^k-1,$ right? It follows that $\max(x,y)\ge(2^k-1)/2=2^{k-1}-\frac12.$ (This is the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).) Since it's an integer, $\max(x,y)\ge2^{k-1}.$

Comment: And if one vertex has that many outgoing or incoming edges, how do I apply the induction hypothesis on it to get a path with k different vertices. In other words how do I move on from there.

Comment: You apply the induction hypothesis to the subgraph formed by the $2^{k-1}$ vertices on the other end of those outgoing (or incoming) edges.